# applet tag vs Object tag

Tags: java

As per W3Schools HTML applet tag is not supported in HTML5. Need to use `<Object>` tag instead of `<applet>` tag.
For more details follow this link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/obsolete.html#the-applet-element
Point 11.2 Non-conforming features
So, I go ahead and the change the code.
Below code that is working with `<APPLET>` tag:

```
<Applet 
      style    = "position:absolute;border:0px;left:184;top:95;height:180;width:364;"
      code     = "jtreeviewapplet.JTreeViewAppletMain.class"
      name     = "TreeView"
      id       = "TreeView"
      hspace   = "0"
      vspace   = "0"
      align    = "top"
      archive  = "/Project/HTML/ABC/XYZ.jar,/Project/HTML/ABC/ABC.jar"
      MAYSCRIPT>


<PARAM NAME="onSelected" VALUE="onSelect_Handler">
      <PARAM NAME="onFinishNormalize" VALUE="onFinishNormalize_Handler">
 </Applet> 
    Here is the snippet; I changed <APPLET> tag to <OBJECT> tag so as to support HTML5 in future:
<OBJECT type=" application/x-java-applet"
      style    = "position:absolute;border:0px;left:184;top:95;height:180;width:364;"     
      name     = "TreeView"
      id       = "TreeView"
      hspace   = "0"
      vspace   = "0"
      align    = "top"    
     >    
  <PARAM name="code" value=”jtreeviewapplet.JTreeViewAppletMain.class”>
  <PARAM name="codebase" value="/Project/HTML/ABC/">
      <PARAM name="archive" value=" XYZ.jar">
      <PARAM name="archive" value=" ABC.jar">     
      <PARAM name="scriptable" value="true">
      <PARAM NAME="onSelected" VALUE="onSelect_Handler">
      <PARAM NAME="onFinishNormalize" VALUE="onFinishNormalize_Handler">
  </OBJECT>
```

After changing the `<applet>` tag to `<object>` tag , my applet itself is not loading and it gives class not found exception for jtreeviewapplet.JTreeViewAppletMain.class.
(Note: For both working and not working condition, I am using latest JDK 1.7 update 9 for compiling the code and in my system I am having latest JRE1.7 update 9 to run the applet code. I am using InternetExplorer 8 and InternetExplorer 9 browser)

Answer (score 1):

Just replacing `applet` by `object` isn't enough. Read http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/63-How-to-use-Java-applets-in-modern-browsers.html for an example.